# What actions count as a suicide?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I see a count of one for my suicide stat in the career section.

I know I died several times caused by myself, falling from a high rooftop, jumping out of driving car, rolled over by my own car, bad motorcycle jump landing, parachute disappears bug, staying in exploding vehicle, leaving to lobby during running match, (not drowned yet but could also count), killing self by grenade....

But I have only a count of one for suicide in solo matches, so I wonder what actions will count for this statistic?

Comment: It should just be any action where you were the cause of your death and others were not involved. Basically if you see your death and your name in the top right kill feed and no other name is associated with it, you killed yourself.

Comment: @n_palum: yes it should be, but as you can see in my listing, it is not that way;)

Comment: Well what time were those games? The career stats have been cleared multiple times leading up to the 1.0 release, and at the 1.0 release.

Comment: i started playing after 1.0 release in december. I must admit that i did not look at the kill feed when dying, but there should have been plenty of times when i accidently killed myself. I hoped that maybe there is a listing with all circumstances which increase the counter, as clearly most of the ones i listed did not count. Only thing i am sure of, when i died with my bycicle yesterday noone else was involved and it said "xyz was killed by a crash", but it did not count as suicide

Comment: Hmm weird.. So they aren't cleared most likely. I mean, sometimes it doesn't count if someone else had a hand in it at all. For example if someone shot the car and set it on fire, they would get the kill if it blew up on you. But besides that the data tracking systems aren't perfect so it may miscount. Overall though, it should general be what you said, and anything that shows up in the feed.

Comment: I think maybe you killed yourself with your own frag grenade...

Comment: @Mandeep Jain:could be, can not remember if that happened to me yet but added it to my list...

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way to get a 'Suicide' would be to grenade yourself

- You can't shoot yourself.
- Jumping out of a vehicule that is going too fast or killing yourself by flipping your bike is 'Died by falling'
- If you kill yourself blowing up in a vehicle it will be 'killed by vehicle explosion'
- If you fall off a cliff or something like that it's 'Died by Falling'
- Dying outside the zone would be 'Killed by BlueZone'
- Dying by the redzone would be 'Killed by RedZone' (happened to me this weekend)
- Leaving the match is not suicide. The character will just stay there, unmoving, until someone or the bluezone kills it.

So with all that, my best guess would be that to get the 'Suicide' message, the only way would be to frag grenade or molotov yourself because it's the only 2 ways I can see of doing yourself damage that doesn't give you some other message.

Comment: The asker is asking about what counts for the suicide stat on the stats page. Do you have anything to support that *only* grenade and Molotov suicides count for the suicide stat?

Comment: It's not a tested answer, but I think I talked about all possible ways to get damage that don't involve somebody else.

Comment: Also need "having a vehicle you just got out of roll over you"

Comment: Like parking a car uphill and letting it rollback on you? Idk what is says.